# Null value received when i send a request contained an array of enum with Postman to Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, http

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO96S.png)

[RequestDTO + response eSexes null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urSDh.png)

[ENUM class ESex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Tcq4.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for what reason, but i solved it changing the name of the variable in the DTO from "eSexes" to "sessi"...very weird